# Recovery of google contacts

Tags: google-contacts

my phone was stolen month ago and despite all my contacts were google contacts, I cannot find them in my account. I thought that if I save my contacts as google contacts, they will automatically appear in my new phone. 
But there is no backup. When I go to contacts.google.com I cannot see them. Nowhere. There are only mail contacts but not my phone contacts. No backup folder found in google disk also. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This means your contacts were not synced properly in stolen phone. While saving contacts you must have saved in google contacts but you might have turned off auto sync of contacts from setting>Accounts>Google>Your_email>Contacts.

Comment: Thank you, Kailash, you are probably right, but I dont know how this happened because last time I changed phone, the contacts recovered automatically, so I supposed  that this will happen again. Very unhappy with this. 

Anyways thank you once again for the response!